# Calculating the time period from time series formla

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have made the following time series formulation:
$$Y_t = (1-K/X)Y_t-1 + PK$$

where $K \leq X$ and $0 \leq P \leq1$.

I'm looking to turn this into a formula to calculate the time period $t$ by only inputting $Y_t$, $K$, $X$ and $P$ as variables.

I can generate a table and plot of $Y_t$ vs $t$ and read from a spreadsheet table.